# Triggering camera on android tablet (with hTML5) doesn't work but it does on iOS

Tags: android, html, ios6, camera

For some reason I can trigger the camera with HTML5 on iOS but not on Android.

How my code works:

I have this line in my code

```
<input type="file" id="btnFrontUpload" name="frontPic" class="filUploadField" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

I initially hide it and then trigger it with this snippet:

```
       // when the visible upload button is clicked - trigger the form field
      $("#btnFrontUploadShow").click(function(){
          $("#btnFrontUpload").click()
      });

      // when the actual upload field is triggered
      $("#btnFrontUpload").change(function (e){

          frontPic = e.target.files[0]
          frontPicName = frontPic.name
          salonId=$("#salonId").val()

          new DisplayUploadImage(frontPic, "btnFrontUploadShow")

      });
```

This is the item that when clicked triggers the file form field.

```
<div class="btnUploads" id="btnFrontUploadShow">Front</div>
```

This works on an iOS6 tablet but on an Android4 tablet?

Comment: In the browser or an app with a webview?

Comment: Does this [test site](http://html5photos.appspot.com/) work with your test device?

Comment: @Tushar sadly I don't have an android tablet, I've just been told by lots of people. So I was hoping someone could see an obvious error in the code.

Comment: @Mark Parnell this is in the browser.

Comment: @Ankur emulator, then?

Comment: @Tushar ... well I don't think that would necessarily be a good test for the camera. Thanks for your help. I was hoping it was an obvious bug. Since it's not that's actually good info for now. I'll get access to a tablet and work on it.